# AEM 6.2 and ReactJS Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, aem

We are building reactJS outside of AEM 6.2 and it works well. After it is added into AEM (v6.2) as a component with AEM templates, it works well except for the routing. Instead of using reactJS routes, the browser tries to load the pages under the AEM folder, which definitely hits 404 error. Any suggestion on how to make the reactJS route work on AEM 6.2? Tks.

Comment: Either you need to use hash navigation or you need to redirect all requests to the react application’s index.html, AEM in every way is focused on MPA architecture, not SPA architecture. Also you can instead use AEM as an api and make fetch request to AEM from a separately hosted react client side application.

Comment: Tks..will give it a shot